# Cmd errorcode output redirection to temporary variable

Tags: windows

I want to redirect my cmd error code output to a temporary variable so that I can apply an if-else condition on that variable to get a required output. The temporary variable may contain error code '0' or '4' depending upon execution of that cmd command. The code I am using is given below-

```
"db2cmd -w -c -i db2 restore db %1 from %2 to d: replace existing" > "<.....temp var.....>"

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 goto Label1
cscript abc.vbs
exit ERRORLEVEL

:Label1
cscript pqr.vbs
exit ERRORLEVEL
```

Can anyone tell how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't already have `ERRORLEVEL` set as a true environment variable (you shouldn't), you can do something like this immediately after running your `db2cmd`:

```
Set db2result=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

If you do this, I'd start your script with:

```
set ERRORLEVEL=
```

Just to make sure you don't run into issues with a true environment variable already existing of the same name.